# Hadoop apache configuration : error connection refused

Tags: java, xml, windows, hadoop

I am trying to configure hadoop on my windows seven using Cygwin on just one   node which named master and slave to localhost

My configuration files are as bellow:

```
hdf-site
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/home/bazargan/hadoop-1.2.1/tmp</value>
<description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>/home/bazargan/data</value>
<description>Comma separated list of paths on the local filesystem of a
DataNode where it should store its blocks. </description>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>/home/bazargan/name</value> 
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
<description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>3</value>
<description>Default block replication.
The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
</description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>

<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/home/bazargan/hadoop-1.2.1/hdfs-tmp</value>
<description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
<description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapred.local.dir</name>
<value>/home/bazargan/hadoop-1.2.1/mapred-tmp</value>
<description>Comma-separated list of paths on the local
filesystem where temporary Map/Reduce data is written.</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>localhost:54311</value>
<description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
and reduce task.</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

when I try to access localhost:50070 it works perfectly but when I want to    access localhost:50030 I got connection refused error.

I really don't know what is causing the error (in log files I also dont see any error for example below is my log of datanode..

ulimit -a for user Mahdi
       core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
       data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
       file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
       open files                      (-n) 256
       pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
       stack size              (kbytes, -s) 2032
       cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
       max user processes              (-u) 256
       virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited

I also turned off my firewall.
   I really appreciate if anyone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Which tutorial are you following? Is the datanode already formatted? Is `jps` command showing all hadoop process?

Comment: which version/distribution of hadoop you are using. Are you using MR V1 or MR v2? Also please provide `mapred-site.xml or yarn-site.xml` file.

Comment: Hi the Jps shows:347876 NameNode
556632 Jps, I have already formatted datanode. The mpred-site .xml is at the end of my post in the code section. I am not sure regarding my version of hadoop.